# What is the (Name for the) Pattern That Couples a Non-Generic Method with a Generic One?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, design-patterns

I have been noticing a pattern in my development, and have seen it for a while, but it struck me that I do not know its technical name, or if it has one.  The reason I am asking this question is that I am building some classes around this behavior and I would like to be technically correct in how I go about naming the components and/or the namespace in which the components will be defined.

Here is a simple example of it in action:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute( object parameter );
}

public interface ICommand<in T>
{
    void Execute( T parameter );
}

public class Command : ICommand<int>, ICommand
{
    public void Execute( object parameter )
    {
        // What is the technical name 
        // of this behavior and/or relationship 
        // with its generics-based counterpart?
        if ( parameter is int )
        {
            Execute( (int)parameter );
        }
    }

    public void Execute( int parameter )
    {
        // We are now in strongly-typed parameter land...
    }
}
```

Essentially, the pattern is this:

1. Take an object that is passed into a method that accepts a `System.Object` parameter.  The best name I can come up with for this at the moment is "generalized object."
2. Determine the type of the generalized object in previous step.  In my example I simply check the object's type.  However, other scenarios could call for value conversion/coercion.
3. Pass the now-strongly-typed object to a strongly-typed counterpart of the generalized method described in the first step.

Is there a name for this pattern?  I am also open to feedback if I am doing something horrendously wrong here and that there is a better/preferred way of going about what I am doing.

Comment: Do you need to implement both interfaces on all of your command classes? You should probably just add a wrapper class implementing `ICommand<object>` which does the check and delegates to a typed inner handler.

Comment: That was the "Unless you assign to a `Nullable`", by he does, so nevermind.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Lee.  I didn't want to complicate the example too much, but you can think of the `ICommand` above as a `System.Windows.Input.Command`.  Another way I have been utilizing this is by simply inheriting `ICommand` (much like how `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable`.  In all cases, a non-generic method is ultimately coupled with a generic method, and the name of this process/pattern is what I am after here.

Comment: I think it is a variation of Command Pattern where instead of pass a  ICommand<in T> in Command constructor you decided to implement it in Command.